# replace recursively shabang with sed

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I'm trying to replace recursively all shabang from a folder (for run program in android..), with sed .
The command works good when i tried with "normal word" but become a headache when i'm trying with shabang..Everything i tried, I got error :

- bad option in substitution expression
- unmatched '/'
- event not found

I'm new to this and it's probably begginer mistake, so here is the code (tsst is my folder):

```
grep -rl "env python" tsst |xargs sed -i "s/\#!/usr/bin/env python/\#!/system/python2.7.9//g"
```

I also tried with variables:(first part of code is good .. i just copy where there's a problem.)

```
sed -i "s/$old/$new/g"

sed -i 's/"$old"/"$new"/g'

sed -i "s/'\#!\/usr\/bin\/env python'/'\#!\/system\/python2.7.9\/'/g"
```

What did i do wrong ?

Comment: Have you tried 1) using `find` instead of `xargs`, 2) this replacement on a single file, 3) a simpler replacement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex. You can't mix `/` as the regex delimiter and actual characters you want to match. You can use any character as the regex delimiter, such as `|`, as long as you use it instead of the `/` in all 3 spots.

```
$ echo '#!/usr/bin/env python'  | sed 's|#!/usr/bin/env python|#!/system/python2.7.9|g'
#!/system/python2.7.9
```

Comment: Thanks you !! It's working fine..I knew its was stupid error.. But i didn't thought to this, now i know and understand why it wasn't working ..